# Xpath and cssselector seems not flexible in case of ::before and ::after

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

**HTML**

```
<li>::before<a href="#county" class="eods-error">::before"County is required."::after</a></li>
```

Based on above html I wrote following :

**Cssselector** : `#eods-error > div > div.eods-error-box > ul > li:nth-child(1)`

**xpath** : `//*[@id="eods-error"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/text()`

I use selenium webdriver and java for automation. To locate an element based on above given **HTML** I used above diff. 2 locators. But seems those can create issue if new element/ div added within html.

Is there any other way to locate above element using some more detail xpath so even if additional **DIV** comes in html then xpath not get failed.

**Screenshot of html section :**

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by additional `div`? Share HTML both for case with *additional `div`* and without it

Comment: @Andersson - I mean what if new element added in between in html, in that case my written xpath/cssseletor might fail.

Comment: Might? It will definitely fail :) Did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below

- XPath

  ```
  //a[@href="#county"]
  ```
- CSS selector

  ```
  a[href="#county"]
  ```

to match required anchor

If you want your current selectors to match it despite of presence/absence of interim `div`, then you might to use below syntax

- XPath. Change

  ```
  //*[@id="eods-error"]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/text()
  ```

  to

  ```
  //*[@id="eods-error"]//div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/text()
  ```
- CSS selector. Change

  ```
  #eods-error > div > div.eods-error-box > ul > li:nth-child(1)
  ```

  to

  ```
  #eods-error div.eods-error-box > ul > li:nth-child(1)
  ```

Note that `/` in XPath and `>` in CSS selector stands for path to immediate child node while `//` in XPath and space in CSS selector - for path to descendant node

Also note that XPath syntax `.../text()` doesn't work in Selenium: instead of locating text node, you should locate parent WebElement and then call `getText()` method